# setTimeout to scrollIntoView in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit, svelte-component

How would i run a bucle to scrollIntoView() in svelte with setTimeout().

I am trying to do an autoSlide.

```
const scrollIntoView = ({currentTarget}) => {
    const scrollToElement = document.querySelector(
        currentTarget.getAttribute('href')
    )

    if (!scrollToElement) return

    scrollToElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
    })
}
```

it is controlled by nav with on:click="{scrollIntoView}"

Answer (score 0):

Add the preventDefault modifier:

```
<a href="#some_id" on:click|preventDefault={scrollIntoView}>...
```

In your current implementation the default is not prevented.
(and by default the browser jumps to the targeted element instantly)

(Not sure what "run a bucle" means or why you'd want a setTimeout)

Comment: that is to make it automatic.

Comment: I don't understand how to make it run automatically in svelte

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to scroll with a delay, it's only a matter of wrapping `scrollToElement.scrollIntoView()` into `setTimeout()`, like so:

```
const scrollIntoView = ({currentTarget}) => {
    const scrollToElement = document.querySelector(
        currentTarget.getAttribute('href')
    )

    if (!scrollToElement) return

    setTimeout(() => {scrollToElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
    }), 1000);    // After 1000 ms
}}
```

But if you're worrying if you can squeeze a `setTimeout()` in the middle of `scrollIntoView()`, then just add it wherever in the callback. [setTimeout() is async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and you don't have to worry about the rest of the callback executing.